# Clang C++ new operator large dynamic array slow compile time

Tags: c++, g++, clang

I am facing a very unusual issue using clang-1200.0.32.21 on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.7.

Essentially, this code takes a long time to compile, and has extremely high RAM usage (peeks around 10GB of RAM):

```
m_Table = new MapGenerator::Block[MAP_DIAMETER * MAP_HEIGHT * MAP_DIAMETER]();

===-------------------------------------------------------------------------===
                      Clang front-end time report
===-------------------------------------------------------------------------===
  Total Execution Time: 50.8973 seconds (55.3352 wall clock)

   ---User Time---   --System Time--   --User+System--   ---Wall Time---  --- Name ---
  34.9917 (100.0%)  15.9056 (100.0%)  50.8973 (100.0%)  55.3352 (100.0%)  Clang front-end timer
  34.9917 (100.0%)  15.9056 (100.0%)  50.8973 (100.0%)  55.3352 (100.0%)  Total
```

Changing it to the following instantly fixes it:

```
uint32_t table_size = Map::MAP_DIAMETER * Map::MAP_HEIGHT * Map::MAP_DIAMETER * sizeof(MapGenerator::Block);
m_Table = reinterpret_cast<MapGenerator::Block*>(malloc(table_size));
memset(m_Table, 0, table_size);

===-------------------------------------------------------------------------===
                          Clang front-end time report
===-------------------------------------------------------------------------===
  Total Execution Time: 1.3105 seconds (2.1116 wall clock)

   ---User Time---   --System Time--   --User+System--   ---Wall Time---  --- Name ---
   1.1608 (100.0%)   0.1497 (100.0%)   1.3105 (100.0%)   2.1116 (100.0%)  Clang front-end timer
   1.1608 (100.0%)   0.1497 (100.0%)   1.3105 (100.0%)   2.1116 (100.0%)  Total
```

If you are curious, these are the relevant definitions:

```
enum : int { MAP_HEIGHT = 15 };
enum : int { MAP_DIAMETER = 1000 };

union Block
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t valid    : 1; // block valid
        /* used to determine visible faces */
        uint8_t v_top    : 1;
        uint8_t v_bottom : 1;
        uint8_t v_front  : 1;
        uint8_t v_back   : 1;
        uint8_t v_right  : 1;
        uint8_t v_left   : 1;
        uint8_t v_base   : 1;
        uint8_t discard  : 1; // delete flag
    };
    uint16_t bits;
};

Block* m_Table;
```

Is there any logical reason as to why new takes this long to compile? To my understanding it should not be different. Also, I do not have this issue on the MSVC (Microsoft C++) compiler on Windows.

EDIT:

This is a minimal reproducible sample:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

enum : int { MAP_HEIGHT = 15 };
enum : int { MAP_DIAMETER = 1000 };

union Block
{
    struct
    {
        uint8_t valid    : 1; // block valid
        /* used to determine visible faces */
        uint8_t v_top    : 1;
        uint8_t v_bottom : 1;
        uint8_t v_front  : 1;
        uint8_t v_back   : 1;
        uint8_t v_right  : 1;
        uint8_t v_left   : 1;
        uint8_t v_base   : 1;
        uint8_t discard  : 1; // delete flag
    };
    uint16_t bits;
};

Block* table = nullptr;

// UNCOMMENT THIS:
// #define USE_MALLOC

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
#ifndef USE_MALLOC
    table = new Block[MAP_DIAMETER * MAP_HEIGHT * MAP_DIAMETER]();
#else
    uint32_t table_size = MAP_DIAMETER * MAP_HEIGHT * MAP_DIAMETER * sizeof(Block);
    table = reinterpret_cast<Block*>(malloc(table_size));
    memset(table, 0, table_size);
#endif

    (void) table;

#ifndef USE_MALLOC
    delete[] table;
#else
    free(table);
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

I compile it with the command:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -g -Wall -Werror -ftime-report -c test.cpp -o test.o
```

Comment: These are absolutely different cases. The operator new constructs each element in the array (applying the implicit constructor), malloc does not. Define the explicit constructor for observing it.

Comment: @S.M. I would expect that to be a runtime performance thing though, this is a compile time issue. GCC doesn't have this issue, nor does MSVC, only clang does this.

Comment: Clang can optimize (pre-count) that array in compile time and just place it as memcpy in runtime.

Comment: I forgot to mention, clang also takes up 10GB of ram with the new operator approach. I added that detail in.